# why struts UI tags can not be put together in the same row?

Tags: struts2

I need 2 textareas in the same row and tried as below but it is printing in the next row.
All struts tags are have same problem.Is there any alternative method ? Please suggest.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<s:textarea name="1"/>
</td>
<td>
<s:textarea name="2"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to Struts2's default rendering based on its default theme.  I find this tutorial gives a good idea of Struts2 theming/templating: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/

If you don't want to use the default and want to lay it out as you have it, try:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<s:textarea name="1" theme="simple"/>
</td>
<td>
<s:textarea name="2" theme="simple"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you like the simple theme then it might be best to set it globally. In your struts.xml add right after the struts tag: 
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />